# Cannot find table for one-to-many relation

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I'm trying to implement one to many relation between two tables:

Main table Merchants

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Merchants {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="id")
    private List<Terminals> terminals;

    @Column
    private String login;
}
```

Second table Terminals which holds merchant id

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Terminals {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="merchant_id")
    private Merchants merchants;

    @Column
    private String mode;
}
```

But then I deploy the code I get exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=163) Table 'production.terminals' doesn't exist
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'production.terminals' doesn't exist
Query is: alter table terminals drop foreign key FKq779ocbhe9oeeor5591t31vx1
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

use below code

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Merchants {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "merchantId", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private int merchantId;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="merchants")
  private List<Terminals> terminals;

  @Column
  private String login;
}



@Entity
@Table
public class Terminals {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="merchantId")
  private Merchants merchants;

  @Column
  private String mode;
}
```

Comment: now I get Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: org.datalis.rest.api.entity.Terminals column: id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false") Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @peter-penzov updated answer. Both tables contains column named "id" . So above issue came. Hope this resolves your mapping problems.

Comment: I already this but now I get Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table 'production.terminals' doesn't exist

Comment: Probably I'm not mapping Entities into Spring properly?

Comment: run this "alter table terminals drop foreign key FKq779ocbhe9oeeor5591t31vx1" query in sqlyog or mysql workbench or any editor then start the application. else drop the tables and start the application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176937/discussion-between-kathirvel-subramanian-and-peter-penzov).